# Under which conditions two different random variables belong to same distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, coupling

I think I understand the idea of coupling given [here from page 18 - 20](https://maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/StochProc34/1516Coupling34.pdf).I specially looked at the example. They are discussing the cases when given random variables have the same distribution with different parameters and in most they are also taking $P(X\leq Y)= 1$.

I want to ask if we have random variables with different distributions for example

$X$~$Poisson$ , $Y$~$Binomial$

$X$~$Exponential$ , $Y$~ $Geometric$

$\vdots$

and we can have $P(Y \leq X) = 1$.

How we are going to do Coupling in such cases and I am not sure how to provide the parameters for distributions. If some example is given that would be really helpful otherwise I would like to know intuition for such scenarios.

Comment: On an intuitive general level, it will be possible to construct $X$ and $Y$ with $P(Y \le X)=1$ providing that the CDF of $Y$ is always above/to the left of (or coincident with) the CDF of $X$. In your specific $X$~$Exponential$ , $Y$~ $Geometric$ case this depends on whether your geometric distributions have support $0,1,2,3,\ldots$ or $1,2,3,\ldots$

Comment: @Henry lets say if we have $X$ ~ $Poisson(1/10)$ , $Y$ ~ $Binomial(100,1/10)$ & $P(X \leq Y  = 1)$. and same distributions with but $P(X \geq Y) = 1$. How we make a decision in such case.

Comment: In your example you have $P(X\le 100)<1=P(Y \le 100)$ so you cannot have $P(X\le Y =1)$.  Also $P(X\le 0)>0.9>0.00003>P(Y \le 0)$ so you cannot have $P(X\ge Y =1)$.  You might do better comparing  something like  $Y=X$ when $X=0$ and $Y=1$ when $X\ge 1$, perhaps in the example $X \sim Poisson(1) $ and  $Y \sim Binomial(1,1-\exp(-1))$